# Android implement undo stack in drawing app

Tags: android, view, runnable, ondraw

I started working on the sample Finger Paint app in the Android SDK to get more familiar with graphics. Lately I've been trying to implement undo/redo, and I've ran into road blocks every way I've tried. I've found a few threads about this, but none have gotten me past these issues. Here are my main 2 trials:

Strategy 1:

Save a stack of the paths (or canvases) and on undo clear the screen and redraw each path except the last one (or reinstate the most recent canvas).

The problem here is likely simple, but I just can't get the view to redraw anything. How do I draw saved paths (or restore a saved canvas)?

Strategy 2:

Save a stack of Bitmaps using getDrawingCache() after each touch. On undo, put the last bitmap back.

The saving has to be ran via post() from a runnable so it executes after onDraw() finishes (post adds it to the system message line after invalidate()). The issue is that when ran from the runnable getDrawingCache() always returns the initial version of the painting, like it can't see any changes after the first.

Why does getDrawingCache(), when called from a runnable, not see the current state of the view?

I've been fighting with this a while. Thanks.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
touch_up();
invalidate();
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    myView.storeView();
    }
};
myView.post(r);
}

public void storeView(){
    historyCount++;
    if(historyCount > historySize) historyCount = 6;    //We don't want more than 6                        
    history.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(myView.getDrawingCache()),historyCount);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For strategy 1, you need to define a data structure that represents all the information needed to render a part of the drawing. So, for instance, if you draw a segment of the drawing by tracking the user's touch position, define a data structure that consists of the current color, drawing shape, and an ArrayList of coordinates used generated by one user gesture. As you follow the user's touch, drawing to the screen, also append the touch coordinates to the ArrayList for the current gesture. When the touch ends, push the data structure onto the undo stack and wait for the next user gesture to create the next structure instance and start populating it.

If you have various gestures (fill, freehand trace, straight line, etc.), you can have a separate structure for each. They can all inherit from an abstract class so they can all go on the stack.

The second strategy strikes me as a horrible memory hog. I think we'd have to see your code to understand why it isn't working as intended.

Comment: 2nd strategy is surely a bad bad approach I would say, in terms of memory. While, this could be fast, but you would hit the OutOfMemory pretty soon with that.

Comment: I added the main code for the second strategy, there's not much to it. I recognize the memory issue, I limit the depth of the stack pretty conservatively. About the data structure, doesn't the path hold all the coordinates and necessary info (except the paint)? I have the history of paths, the issue I have is redrawing them.

Comment: Did you enable caching for myView (by calling `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`)?

Comment: @Ted yes I did. The current drawing saves correctly until I wrap it in a runnable.